# Complex JSON serialization with an odd list issue - Using Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a class that has a list of objects as seen in the first class below.

```
public class AddComponentToChangeGroupParams
{
    [JsonProperty]
    static string Id = "1";
    public List<Component> Component{ get; set; }
}

public class Component
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ControlName> Controls { get; set; }
}

public class ControlName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need this to output:

```
{
"Id": 1,
"Component": {
    "Name": "nameOfComponent",
    "Controls": [
        {"Name": "name of control"},
        {"Name": "name of control 2"}
        ]
    },
"Component": {
    "Name": "nameOfComponent2",
    "Controls": [
        {"Name": "name of control"},
        {"Name": "name of control 2"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Do you really? That seems to be quite ugly, repeating the "Component" property twice. While perhaps not strictly disallowed by the JSON spec, it does seem unusual and might break many existing parsers.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it can be done using `JsonConverter`:

```
public class AddComponentToChangeGroupParamsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite => true;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var addComponentToChangeGroupParams = (AddComponentToChangeGroupParams)value;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("Id");
        // I made Id public for simplicity you can use reflection to get value if you want
        writer.WriteValue(AddComponentToChangeGroupParams.Id); 

        foreach (var component in addComponentToChangeGroupParams.Component)
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName("Component");
            serializer.Serialize(writer, component);
        }

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

As you can see you take full responsibility for serializing `AddComponentToChangeGroupParams` class so you need to write all properties in this converter.

To enable this add `[JsonConverter(typeof(AddComponentToChangeGroupParamsConverter))]` on `AddComponentToChangeGroupParams`.

Comment: Perfect, I knew it needed a custom JsonConveter I just dont have that much experience with it. I will give it ago tomorrow.